# how to get key of null value in associative array in php

Tags: php

i am doing validation of html form in php, I want to print out the key of an empty field,

```
$url = $_POST['url']; $start_time = $_POST['start_time']; $end_time = $_POST['end_time'];

$arr = array("Url"=>"$url","Start Time"=>"$start_time","End Time"=> "$end_time");
```

Comment: `foreach($arr as $key => $val) { if (empty($val)) { echo $key; }}`

Comment: one more question, when i use    $_POST['url' . 'start_time' . 'end_time']; instead  it still show me correct answer but browser also shows the Notice: Undefined index... why is that?

Comment: you can't make up your own syntax.,you're checking if you submitted `<input type="text" Name="urlstart_timeend_time">`, which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of....

```
$url = $_POST['url']; $start_time = $_POST['start_time']; 
$end_time = $_POST['end_time'];
```

I'd suggest

```
$err =0;
 // repeat following block for every mandatory input
if ((isset($_POST['url']) && (!empty($_POST['url']))){
$url = $_POST['url'];
} else {$err++;  $errmsg .='You need to enter a URL<br>';}
```

...

```
if ($err > 0){
echo $errmsg;
} else {
// process submitted form 
}
```

eg, I prefer to look for errors first, before doing anything with a user provided variable.